# Object field mapping problem when mapping MapStruct List to List

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a problem when mapping a List from a List.
All default fields of Entity are well mapped.

ex) (Entity)String date -> (DTO) String date

However, the Join object field exists in Entity.

We need to pull the data out of this object field and map it anew.

In the case of a single Entity to single DTO rather than a List to List, this was easily possible.

```
@Mapping(target = ".", source = "user")
```

This way we were able to map all fields of the user object field that the Entity has to the remaining unmapped fields.

However, trying the same on a List has no effect.

Which method should I use?

```
@Entity(name = "refund")
public class RefundEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int refundId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserEntity user;

private int refundAmount;

}
```

and

```
public class AdminRefundUserDto {

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class Response {

    private int refundAmount;
    private String marketName;
    private String bizNumber;
    private String bizUserName;

    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid4")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid4")
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID userId;
private String userName;
private String password;
private String phoneNumber;
private String marketName;
private String bizUserName;
private String bizNumber;
}
```

and I used

```
@Mapping(target = ".", source = "refundList.user")
List<AdminRefundUserDto.Response> toDtoList(List<RefundEntity> refundList);
```

Comment: Can you share the Source class, Target class and the mapper you implemented?

Comment: Added code. sorry for inconveniencing to you.

Comment: Look at this guide on how to map collections with MapStruct.  https://www.baeldung.com/java-mapstruct-mapping-collections

Comment: I read that guide before asking the question.

And after re-reading after your advice, it's still hard to figure out what the problem is.

If my problem is a solvable problem, can you tell me some key keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, create a method for the mapper with a SourceObject parameter that return a TargetObject

```
@Named("toResponseDto")
//add your mapping
AdminRefundUserDto.Response toResponseDto(RefundEntity refundEntity);
```

if you have complex logic of mapping, you can also create a custom method to map a certain target parameter: see [Custom Mapper with MapStruct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper)

Then add an IterableMapping

```
@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "toResponseDto")
List<AdminRefundUserDto.Response> toDtoList(List<RefundEntity> refundList);
```

Comment: You are my savior! Your answer is so perfect!

Comment: you are my savior! thank you it works!