# Problem with mapstruct java: Can't generate mapping method from iterable type to non-iterable type

Tags: java, swagger, dto, mapstruct

I am new to java programming trying to do dto mapping,to implement data filtering

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Request {
    List<EventType> eventType;
    String eventRef;
    List<Status> status;
    LocalDate DateFrom;
    LocalDate DateTo;
}

public class FilterDto   {

  @JsonProperty("eventType")
  @Valid
  private List<EventTypeEnum> eventType = null;

  @JsonProperty("eventRef")
  private String eventRef;

  @JsonProperty("status")
  @Valid
  private List<StatusEnum> status = null;

  @JsonProperty("DateFrom")
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
  private LocalDate DateFrom;

  @JsonProperty("DateTo")
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
  private LocalDate DateTo;
```

map struct func

```
Request map(List<FilterDto> filter);
```

I call this mapper in the controller

```
Request request = registryMapper.map(regPageReqDto.getFilter());
```

regPageReqDto generated class in swagger, which contains FilterDto

Comment: Are you sure you need to map a list of FilterDto into one single Request object? For me it looks more like you have to map each FilterDto to a separate Request object. If you have more than one FilterDto, you can use @IterableMapping to map a list of FilterDto  into a list of Request.

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan Yes, I need to filter each object with each other, thx for answer, 
I will try to use your advice

Comment: So, if I understand it well, you can look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73247962/13115701